# Last Digit of the Sum of Fibonacci Numbers in range a to b

Tags: c++, algorithm, fibonacci

my solution is failing the test case 1234 12345 in the output and it is giving output 2 instead of correct output 8 although some of the test cases in the question sample have passed . please point out my mistake. thank you.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int calc_fib(long long n) {
    long long int m, o = 0, p = 1, q = 1;
    m = (n+2) % 60;

    for(long long int i = 2 ; i <= m ; i++) {
        q = o + p;
        o = p;
        p = q;
    }

    //if m=0 then q should be 0 and not 1 so base case
    if(m == 0) q = 0;

    return q;
}

int main() {
    long long a, b;
    cin>>a>>b;

    int result1 = calc_fib(b);
    int result2 = calc_fib(a-1);
    int final_result = ((result1%10) - (result2%10) + 10) % 10;

    cout<<final_result;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `(n+2) % 60` ?

Comment: If you are doing `calc_fib(b)` anyway, you can just collect the result in a separate variable when `i` reaches `a` and on wards. This way, you can avoid `calc_fib(a-1);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Also, can you share a link to the problem?

Comment: Yes thank you @vivek_23 for that comment. Collecting the result and storing in a separate variable is a better way to do it. Thanks. I have shared the image of the question as well now.

Comment: @AanchalChaurasia Would you mind sharing the link?

Comment: It's from a course I've doing from Coursera so the link can't be shared. Only if you enrol for the course you'll be able to see the assignment questions. :/

Comment: Thank you @Yunnosch . I'll be sure to keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing `calc_fib(b)` anyway, you can just collect the result in a separate variable when i reaches a and on wards. This way, you can avoid `calc_fib(a-1)`;

If this is for a single range of `a` to `b`, you can compute on the fly, else precompute them by caching them in an array and just do `calc_fib(b) - calc_fib(a-1)`.

You are doing

```
    q = o + p;
    o = p;
    p = q;
```

This will lead to integer overflow since fibonacci numbers can become large after 20<sup>th</sup> or so.

Find `last digit of sum of all fibonacci from a to b` *is equivalent to* `just sum all last digits of each fibonacci from ath term to bth term`. So, you can just keep MODing it by `10`, both for sum as well as the numbers.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> // use any other alternative for this as it doesn't seem to be a good practice

using namespace std;

int calc_fib(long long a,long long b) {
    if(b <= 2) return b;
    int prev = 1,curr = 1,sum = a < 3 ? 2 : 0;
    long long int i = 1;
    for(i = 3; i <= b; ++i){
        curr += prev;
        prev = curr - prev;
        if(i >= a){
            sum = (sum + curr) % 10;
        }       
        prev %= 10;
        curr %= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    long long a = 0, b = 0;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<calc_fib(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @vivek_23 . This was really helpful and detailed answer. Thanks a lot!